# C++ game trainer process monitoring

Tags: c++, winapi, memory, process

I am going to open game process from my trainer app and write some values to memory. I have no problems with opening a process and writing a value to memory. But I can't realize how to monitor the game process availability. For example I opened a running process, user closed it and opened again. How can I track this in my code? OpenProcess handle is valid even after the process is closed (until CloseHandle called). Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `GetExitCodeProcess` function to see if the handle you have points to a running process.

```
DWORD exitCode=0;
::GetExitCodeProcess(hProcess, &exitCode);
if (exitCode==STILL_ACTIVE)
  ; //process is alive
```

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683189%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Or else, if it's more suitable for your application to have the process termination event signalled to you (process is a waitable object):

```
::WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, dwTimeout);
```